# Setting EditText from selected item on ListView?

Tags: android, android-listview

I've been trying to set and EdiText on my activity when a ListView is called and an item is selected but everything I have tried doesn't work. How I have it setup is Main.class button opens ListView.class, iterm is slected on ListView and the sets EditText on Main.class with that value.

Here is my code:

Main.class:

```
public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            switch(arg0.getId()){
                case R.id.bSetListItem:
                            Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(),
                              PhotoDialog.class);
                    startActivityForResult(i, GET_ITEM);
                    break;  
        }
        }


protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
     { 
         super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data); 

         switch(requestCode) {
             case PICK_ITEM:
     // handle the contact result
                 Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
                 String val = extras.getString("item");
                 itemName.setText(val);

                 break;
         }
     }
```

ListView.class:

```
    public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View v, int position,long id) {             
    Intent data = new Intent(this,Main.class);
data.putExtra("key","SELECTED ITEM");    
setResult(RESULT_OK, Intent data);
    }
```

Comment: nm... I figured it out.I didn't tell the setResult which activity. This code worked below.

 `Intent i = new Intent();
        i.putExtra("response", "Response from second");
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, i);
        finish();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you didn't finish your list activity when you start your activity for result you must finish your activity by calling finish() method

```
public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View v, int position,long id) {             
    Intent data = new Intent();
    data.putExtra("item","SELECTED ITEM");    
    setResult(RESULT_OK, data);
    finish();
}
```

another thing is whatever key you have to set into put time same that key was used for getting time

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
 { 
     super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data); 

     switch(requestCode) {
         case PICK_ITEM:
 // handle the contact result
             Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
             String val = extras.getString("item");
             itemName.setText(val);

             break;
     }
 }
```

Edit:

you have set the "this" and "Main.class" into the intent, when you start activity for result and set the data then no need to set the context object and class name into the Intent constructor. The Intent() constructor was empty call and just put the data you want to set as result

Answer (score 0):

Just set up a public static String in your ListView class, then in your Main class, call

itemName.setText(ListView.string);